# How to Hide specific cell value in datagridview

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, datagridview, c#-3.0

I have the Database,that contains a table like so :

```
 id  | Description|  Rate    | ...
-----+------------+----------+------
 1   |  Product1  |  200     | ...
 2   |  Product2  |  200     | ...
 3   |  Product1  |  200     | ...
 ... |  ...       |  ...     | ...
```

Now I need to hide the specific cell value i.e. `Product1` as in column Description

It should be like empty value to be displayed on datagridview :

```
 id  | Description|  Rate    | ...
-----+------------+----------+------
 1   |  Product1  |  200     | ...
 2   |  Product2  |  200     | ...
 3   |            |  200     | ...
 ... |  ...       |  ...     | ...
```

Comment: Can't you remove it form the datasource?

Comment: All you will be able to do is hide the row using a filter on the underlying data source. Hiding individual cells is not possible...

Answer (score 4):

You can handle the DataGridView.CellPainting event to identify the cell you want to customize.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
 // We are interested in handling the values in the "Description" column only..
 if (e.ColumnIndex == DescriptionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index)
 {
     string description="something";
     if (e.Value != null)

     {
         if (e.Value.ToString()==description)
         {
             e.CellStyle.ForeColor = e.CellStyle.BackColor;
             e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor;
         }
     }
 }
}
```